# Unbundle throws " abort: error: ftp error: no host given" when using a local network share with an UNC path

Tags: mercurial

Before explaining my problem let me tell you the Mercurial setup,

We have the following repos,

RELEASE
DEVELOPMENT
BUGFIX

All the above repo are running on a central server using IIS and hgwebdir.cgi

Now coming to the problem,

1. I clone a local repo from DEVELOPMENT repo.
2. I make changes to the clone and commit (Not push).
3. I make a bundle from the clone and pass the bundle to QA who has cloned the RELEASE repo.
4. Now I try to apply the bundle to the RELEASE repo clone using hg unbundle
5. I get an error, abort: error: ftp error: no host given

What am I doing wrong? Can you give solution to the above problem keeping a Windows setup in mind?

Answer (score 4):

It really sounds like you have a syntax error in your unbundle command.  The normal usage is just:

```
hg unbundle c:\path\to\the.bundle
```

there's no ftp involved unless you're trying to use a ftp:// URL which isn't supported.  Is it possible you have a directory named ftp and the parser is mistakign it for a component in a ftp URL?

Also, most folks wouldn't use bundles in the scenario you're describing.  They'd just do:

```
hg push URL-or-file-path-to-QA
```

and push direct to QA's own repo (not to RELEASE)

People generally use bundles only when a network connection isn't possible or practical.

Comment: Actually we are planning to setup a review process by sending a patches periodically to a team lead so that he can review by applying patches. Also we want to build up a history of patches for future reviews.

Comment: Have you considered something like reviewboard?  It's excellent, and has great mercurial interaction.

Comment: Yep trying Review Board. Have it installed on my central server but not got the time to configure it for mercurial :) Should be doing that.

Comment: It's really great integration.  Heartily recommended.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem, I don't think hg likes uncs.

I mapped \server\DevSourceCode\Mercurial to R: and it worked fine, see below:

```
R:\Repositories\myproj>hg unbundle  \\server\DevSourceCode\Mercurial\ChangeBundles\myproj_changes.hg
abort: error: ftp error: no host given

R:\Repositories\myproj>hg unbundle  R:\ChangeBundles\myproj_changes.hg
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 0 changesets with 0 changes to 139 files
(run 'hg update' to get a working copy)
```